# Duplicate Python Paths differ in Terminal and Python IDE

Tags: python, macos, terminal

whenever I try to get a module in python, it only works in terminal and I asked someone and they said I had multiple python paths and that terminal was using the correct one.(something like that). I go into my terminal and find python directory but there are multiple things there and I don't know what to do delete. 
this is what is shown:

```
astroid                 pylint
astroid-2.3.3.dist-info         pylint-2.4.4.dist-info
isort                   six-1.14.0.dist-info
isort-4.3.21.dist-info          six.py
lazy_object_proxy           wrapt
lazy_object_proxy-1.4.3.dist-info   wrapt-1.11.2-py3.8.egg-info
mccabe-0.6.1.dist-info
```

I have no idea what to uninstall

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: It's not about uninstalling anything, it's about having the correct evn setup.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't really understand what that link means

Comment: Your issue is with where Python searches for modules.

Comment: do you know that, do you have 2 version of python or no? (2.7 and 3.x). if you have 2 seprated version of python, you should find their path("which python" or "whereis python" command). if you find them, tell us.

Comment: i think this is your python's path: "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/" or in this path: "/usr/bin  ------------ tell us what you see in this directory about python name

Comment: @SiGNoR I didnt know that and I have 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and a folder called current

Comment: ok, run this command : "python --version" , and tell me the version

Comment: @SiGNoR its 2.7.16. I always thought I was on 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS is based on a BSD code base, while Linux is an independent development of a unix-like system. Most of the times, MacOS and Linux has 2 different versions of python(By default MacOS ships with Python-2.7).
if you want to use python-3 and its modules, you should change somtehing on MacOS.

if you don't have version 3.x of python, install it with this command:

```
brew install python
```

and then change the alias of python, in the terminal. run:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

then you can pass in the last line:

```
    if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
    fi

    alias python='python3.8'
    alias pip= 'pip3'
```

after all, run:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: I did ```  ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python  ``` as you said the tried ```python --version``` but its still the same version as before (2.7.16)

Comment: tell me the result of this command: ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*

Comment: well I see python3.8 and python3.8-config so I would assume so but apparently not if latest for Mac is 3.7.7

Comment: its too long for me to paste the whole result but its basically in the format of ```lrwxr-xr-x  1 kamilleocadie-olsen  admin  26  2 Apr 17:28 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.7.7```

Comment: Its a repetition of above but with different python versions I believe

Comment: im sorry to be annoying but I don't really understand what you want me to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210816/discussion-between-kamil-leocadie-olsen-and-signor).

Comment: you cahnge the alias name for this reason: when you run 'python' the python v 3.8 will be run. insteat of v 2.7